# Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имён User

Tags: c#, library

Работаю над приложением, разделила логику и интерфейс на 2 библиотеки классов, одна почему-то не воспринимает другую и получается ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код файла Program.cs , где и возникает ошибка.

```
using System;
using BLL.Model;

namespace Portal
{
   
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать!");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя пользователя");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            var user = new User();

        }
    }
}
```

Почему так происходит? В чём ошибка?

Comment: Режим ванги: `User` приватный, либо вы не добавили библиотеку в зависимости.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар примерно то же говорит: написано `class User {}` а по умолчанию это значит то же самое, что и `private class User`. Но давайте всё же по науке: скриншот сделайте такой, в котором РАСКРЫТ узел "зависимости" и покажите код класса User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом случаем, чтобы сборка EducationapPartial увидела сборку Bll, необходимо сделать следующее.

1. В EducationapPartial раскрыть зависимости и нажать правок клавишей на "Проекты" и выбрать "Добавить". В появившемся окне добавить проект Bll.
2. В Program.cs вы указываете using на необходимый namespace.
3. Как подсказали коллеги, не должно быть ошибок с модификаторами доступа. Так что не забывайте про public у методов и классов, которые вызываются у зависимых проектов.

Всё, других проблем быть не должно. Также запрещается использовать циклические зависимости. Если они появляются в проекте, значит вы что-то проектируете неправильно. Рекомендую ознакомиться с CleanArchitecture или Луковой архитектурой. Также майкрософт в документации выдавал рекомендации на проектирование микросервисов. Удачи.